How to put the bounds on the integrals when calculating the area of a regular surface?
I came across this problem. Let
$$C=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\:|\:x^2+y^2\leq3x\leq3y\}$$
Compute the area of $C$ using polar coordinates.
I put the surface coordinates in polar coordinates, which gives
$$r^2 \leq 3r\cos(\theta ) \leq 3r\sin(\theta )$$
But how am i supposed to put this on the integral? I tried to put $$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$ and $$ 0 \leq r \leq 3\cos(\theta )$$ but the integral came in hard way, so i doubt its true.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

thanks, i could not find the /leq for some reason.

Actually, it's \leq.

Hint
You get
\begin{align*}
\mathcal C&=\{(r,\theta )\mid 0\leq r\leq 3\cos (\theta) \text{ and } \cos(\theta )\leq \sin(\theta )\}\\
&=\left\{(r,\theta )\mid 0\leq  r\leq 3\cos (\theta) \text{ and } \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \right\}.
\end{align*}

oooh, did not consider using the cos and sin, makes sense. thank you!

i do not understand, though, why θ is bounded between π/4 and π/2. when θ=π doesn't the condition hold?

Because  $ \cos(\theta )\geq 0$. @andreone
